# JSON Flat file vs DB querying

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I'm working on a site that has a store locator built in.

Since I have similar sites developed in the past, I have experienced some troubles when I had search peaks hitting the database (mySQL) hard.
All these past location search engines were querying the database to get the results.

Now I have taken a different approach, but since I'm not 100% sure, I thought that asking this great community could make me feel more secure about this direction or stick to what I did before.

So for this new search, instead of hitting the database for requests, I'm serving the search with a JSON file that regenerates (querying the database) only when something is updated, created or deleted on the locations list.

- My doubt is, can a high load of requests over the json file have the same effect than a high load of query requests over the database?
- Serving the search results from a JSON to lower the impact on db (and server resources) is a good approach or it's not a good idea?

Maybe someone out there had to take the same decision and can share the experience with me, or maybe you just know how things really are and recommend me a certain approach.

Answer (score 1):

Flat files are the poor man's db and can be even more problematic than a heavily pounded database. For example reading and writing the file still requires a lock, and will not scale, as the same file may not be accessible to all app servers.

My suggestion would be any one of the following:

1. Benchmark your current hardware, identify bottlenecks, scale out or up accordingly.
2. Implement a caching layer, this will save on costly queries for readonly data.
3. Consider more high performant storage solutions such as [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/)
4. Implement a real full text search engine such as [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) or [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

---

Response to comment #1:

---

You could accomplish the same thing without having to read/write a flat file (which must be accessible by all app servers), by caching the data. Here's just a quick N dirty rundown of how I would do it:

**Zip + 10 miles:**

Query database, pull store data, json_encode, cache using a key construct like 92562_10, then store in cache. Now when other users enter 92562 + 10 they will pull data from cache vs the database (or flat file).

**City, State + 50 miles:**

Same as above, except key construct may look like murrieta_ca_50.

But with the caching layer you get better performance, and the cache server will be available to all your app servers, which would be much easier than having to install/configure NFS to share the file on a network.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks so much for your council. 
I was reading this from google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 and I was seeing that they pull out an xml file from a db query (similar to what I'm doing but xml instead of json). Is this still bad considering the map is reading a flat file in this case as well? Thanks so much again.

Comment: No, in that case, the xml file is essentially a 'cache'. The goal is to reduce the number of lookups against the more expensive database store. With a caching (or flatfile) solution you could prewarm the cache whereby you can issue a query to return all the results then populate cache (or create flatfile(s)). But I would recommend using JSON regardless due to it's portability.